# Should I use a comma before the conjunction in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, commas, conjunctions

The sentence

> The movie was loud and the chatter was louder.

Should I need to add a comma before the `and` that joins the first sentence `The movie was loud` and the independent clause `the chatter was louder`?

Which one is correct?

> 1. The movie was loud and the chatter was louder.
> 2. The movie was loud, and the chatter was louder.

I am not a native English speaker. Please explain your answer too.

Comment: I imagine the second would be correct, but I'm not sure, and I don't know exactly why :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, "and" is a [coordinating conjunction](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/598/01/) connecting two independent clauses, so a comma is required; #2 is correct.